# Trying to make certain category names dynamic results in 100% server memory usage

Tags: category, plugin, memory

My custom module has certain categories that are linked to certain customers and should return that customer's company name instead of the category name, I have written a plugin like this:

```
public function afterGetName(Category $subject, $result) {
    $customerCollection = $this->customerCollectionFactory
        ->create()
        ->addFieldToFilter('custom_category_id', $subject->getId())
        ->setPageSize(1);

    if ($customerCollection->getSize()) {
        return $this->customerRepository->getById($customerCollection->getFirstItem()->getId())->getAddresses()[0]->getCompany();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This works perfectly, but when I clear the cache the server starts using 100% memory and will slow to a crawl. I have narrowed it down to the `$this->customerRepository->getById` call, but I don't see how this seemingly results in an infinite recursion. I have tried using an `AddressRepository` instead, but that somehow breaks all `$customer->getCustomAttribute` calls.

Comment: Couldn't you just get the customer from the currently logged in session in that case?

Comment: The customer that's linked to the category is usually different from the currently logged in customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't understand how using customer or address repositories in a `$category->getName` plugin breaks your entire Magento installation, I managed to make it work by making a custom customer collection that also includes the default biling address' company, which allows me to simply call `$customer->getCompany`.

```
<?php

namespace {Namespace}\{Module}\Model\ResourceModel\Customer;

/**
 * Class Collection
 * @package {Namespace}\{Module}\Model\ResourceModel\Customer
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection {
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect() {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->joinAttribute(
            'company',
            'customer_address/company',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```